# How can I add text under images that I have aligned horizontally in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am a newb.  I have finally figured out how to get images aligned on my main page in my index.html along with code in my default.css.

Now I would like to add text under each image.  I know this should be easy, but am not able to find anything that seems to work.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<div id="random">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="3.jpg" />
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
#random{ 
     max-width: 650px
}

#random img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your images in a container, and put the text under them.  Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/8xf2N/1/

```
<div id="random">
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="1.jpg" />
      <p>Image One</p>
    </div>
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="2.jpg" />
      <p>Image Two</p>
    </div>
    <div class='img-container'>
      <img src="3.jpg" />
      <p> Image Three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#random{ 
     max-width: 650px
}

#random img{
    width:80px;
}

.img-container{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the HTML 5 figure tag. (Assuming your website is follwoing HTML 5 standards). That way, you can nest a  tag and style them.

```
<div id="random>
    <figure>
         <img src="1.jpg"/>
         <figcaption>Your Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

That way you have selectors to style them with CSS as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#random{ 
     max-width: 650px
}

#random .image-wrap{
    display:inline-block;
    width:80px;
}


<div id="random">
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img src="1.jpg" />
        <p>Text for image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <p>Text for image 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-wrap">
        <img src="2.jpg" />
        <p>Text for image 2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the images in a div. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a6pNw/

CSS:

```
#random{ 
 max-width: 650px
}

#random div{
 display:inline-block;
 width:80px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="random">
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```